# How to use FaceDetector.class to return the number of faces in a photo

Tags: java, android

I need to implement some lines of code that, given a bitmap Image, returns to me an int that represents the number of faces in the image. How can I do it using this Class: [FaceDetector.Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector) ?

For now I did it in a really symple way:

```
Bitmap bmp = image.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),5);
//int numberFaces = faceDetector.findFaces(image,"Face[faces]");??
```

I am not understanding what to insert in *Face[faces]*and precisely I am confused about what .findFaces() does (it's the unique method of this Class).

I am sorry if I am not more accurate, but I am not understanding completely this class maybe.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please show the community what you've already tried so they can help you with specific problems.

Comment: I edited trying to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html#findFaces(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.media.FaceDetector.Face%5B%5D)). To quote:

> Face: an array in which to place all found FaceDetector.Faces. The
>   array must be sized equal to the maxFaces value set at initialization

So just pass an empty array of size maxFaces. In your example:

```
Bitmap bmp = image.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
int maxFaces = 5;
FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),maxFaces);
Face[] faces = new Face[maxFaces];
int numberFaces = faceDetector.findFaces(image,faces);
//findFaces should've filled the faces array if it detected any, and you can use it.
```

Comment: So is enough if i add a line like this: Face faces[] = new Face[5];?

Comment: Yes, that's it.